# My MacBook Air keeps restarting

Tags: macbook-pro

My MacBook Air keeps restarting and won't pass the apple sign. I tried to reinstall the system but it says I don't have enough disk space to install and needs to remove something. What should I do?

Comment: How did you try to reinstall the system?

Comment: Can you boot in [Verbose Mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201573) to see what messages are being generated.  Hold Cmd=V while powering up.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a **Time Machine backup** on an external (USB, FireWire) hard drive? If so, boot to Recovery (Apple + R), erase the drive and reinstall OS X, then restore your data via Migration Assistant.

Your core issue here is **you do not have enough space on your hard drive for all your data**. You're going to have to either:
 - Delete some of your data or
 - Clone the old hard drive to a larger drive (this is the perfect time to upgrade to a SSD, also).